# Singular Value Decomposition using Java and Jama library

Tags: java, svd, jama

I want to write some code which calculates matrices U, S and V of a matrix using Jama library, in Java. How can I calculate the SVD, but using threads, a thread for every matrix(U, S and V). I'm working with very large matrices,and I need threads because I have to reduce the running time to a third.How can I achieve that?